# ASP .Net Get IP camera stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, ip-camera

I'm using the following code for getting an IP camera stream :

```
    private void Display()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream receiveStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");

            using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(receiveStream))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
                while (true)
                {
                    int nbrByte = receiveStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (nbrByte == 0)
                        break;

                    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, nbrByte);

                    Response.Clear();
                    //Response.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errMsg = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

Nothing is happening when I run the code. Using the browser and after login I can see the video. Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you run the code? Do you check the exceptions you just discard? Where is this code located? Why are you using `Clear()` when its meaning is "discard anything I tried to send earlier" and you clearly want to send something?

Comment: I'm using the code in a asp.net code behind webpage on the page load if (!IsPostBack).  The code is not throwing an exception. And also i had the same behavior without the Response.Clear(); Thanks

Comment: Most cameras *stream* video over RTSP not over HTTP. HTTP may load the initial page but that page then loads a control (often antiquated ActiveX controls) which then receives and displays a stream.  What URL are you loading? Is it the same URL as you can view in your browser? If so, this will never work.